# Spring batch writing to different tables conditionally with ItemWriter (ItemProcessor output to Table_A if success or Table_B if fail)

Tags: spring-batch

I am reading from source table (using JpaPagingItemReader) and passing to ItemProcessor.
My requirement is if Item is processed successfully then it should write to TABLE_A and if processing failed then write to TABLE_B.
I got it working, but I dont feel it as nice way.
My current implementation is

```
// my processor
public class MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<SourceEntity, BaseOutputEntity>{

    @Override
    public BaseOutputEntity process(SourceEntity input) {
       // NOTE: EntityA, EntityB both extend BaseOutputEntity
       try {
           EntityA a = callMyBusiness.method(input);
           return a;
       } catch (MyBusinessException e) {
           EntityB b = createMyFailureObj(input)
           return b;
       }
   }
}

// my itemwriter
public class MyItemWriter extends JpaItemWriter<MyBaseOutputEntity> {
    // donthing as JpaItemWriter methods will take care
}
```

It is doing functionally what exactly I want.
One drawback of above is when I see job execution / step execution history, I can't know how many are successful or how many are failure, as it shows e.g. if 100 reads then 100 writes.

Can anyone suggest better approach. Are conditional steps useful here?

Answer (score 2):

You can throw an exception on your processor, and declare this Exception as Skipable (if not, chunck will be broken).

If you implements an [ItemProcessListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemProcessListener.html) you can catch the invalid item on the onProcessError(Entry item, Exception t) function and write it on the table B. 
(Read the documentation carefully: Some listeners functions are on transactions, others not)

At the end of the batch, writedItemsCount is the number of valids item, skippedItemCount is the number of invalid items.

Other way to write in different tables is use the [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html) with the BackToBackPatternClassifier but you loose the count of invalid items.